# Qt QML MenuBar and Menus not showing

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm new to Qt and Qt/QML and I am trying to setup a menubar but it doesn't show it at all.

I've copied pasted the code and still nothing(from Qt doc).

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true;
    width: 1000;
    height: 700;
    title: "App";
    MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: "File"
            MenuItem { text: "Open..." }
            MenuItem { text: "Close" }
        }

        Menu {
            title: "Edit"
            MenuItem { text: "Cut" }
            MenuItem { text: "Copy" }
            MenuItem { text: "Paste" }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you getting any error or warding in console ?

Comment: All is clean.No errors,the window properties are set.

Comment: Which OS are you using? With your code on Mac OS X 10.8 I see the menu bar but not inside the app, I see them inside the top menu bar in the OS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved it by using

`menuBar: MenuBar{//Menubar content}`

instead of

`MenuBar{//Menubar content}`

Comment: You should mark this as the answer. (You should see an empty check mark next to it that you can click)

Comment: +1 Man they really need to fix the documentation in Qt. I'm sure everybody copy and paste the example, then realize it doesn't work, and find this question/answer.